# Telerik Winforms Theme Title Bar Don't show up

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am using Telerik-Winforms templates, and unfortunately when I create a RadForm with one of the templates, the title bar is bugged - means instead of seeing the chosen theme title bar,
I see my normal windows 7 title bar.

Do you have any idea why could that happen?

As seen in visual studio vs actual window:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the aero effect by setting the **AllowAero** property to *false*, which will enable the desired appearance of the title bar.

Comment: I have tested this before sharing it with you. The tests were performed with RadControls for WinForms Q1 2012